# Maven Build Error: Unable to download jar - Network is unreachable

Tags: maven

maven INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Network is unreachable

I am getting this issue, when I build using maven

Comment: Is your internet connection working? and maven repo is not blocked by anything?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the above problem:

I looked into the maven installed location which is 
/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9

Now open conf directory and look for the settings.xml

The problem lied in the proxy settings in this file:

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
    <id>myproxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host></host>
    <port></port>
    .....
</proxies>
```

search for proxies and add your proxy detail between `<host></host>` tags
and port detail between `<port></port>`

This will solve the network related or proxy related issue.

Best of Luck !!!

Comment: This is not the cause this is commented out by default. You should configure a settings.xml in your home folder $HOME/.m2/settings.xml...